# Android: Overriding RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

My RelativeLayout has some padding, but for a certain SurfaceView I want it to have no padding.  I set the padding to 0dp, yet it still follows the RelativeLayout.  How do I override it?

Comment: can you explain this a bit more

Comment: @anddevmanu I have a RelativeLayout which has padding, so then every element gets padding.  However let's say I want a Button that doesn't have padding.  I tried setting the android:paddingLeft to 0dp for only that Button, but it still ended up visually with padding, so I think it still followed RelativeLayout.  I want that Button's layout to be different from the RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your root layout has set padding then even if you set 0dp padding to the child views the will have the padding due to root layout.use the nested layout and assign the padding to layouts you want.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                          android:orientation="horizontal"
                          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout><surfaceview></surfaceview></RelativeLayout>  //add padding here if you want

<RelativeLayout><Button></Button></RelativeLayout>  //do not add padding here if you do not want
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have set padding for RelativeLayout, not SurfaceView.

You can get the instance of RelativeLayout and set the padding at run-time using below code:

```
RelativeLayout element = MainLayout.findViewById(id);

   if (element!= null)
      element.setPadding(0.0.0.0);
```

**Other Approach:**

You can create your own widget and use them in your Layout file.

```
package com.android.xxx
public class MyRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {

}
```

in Your Layout file, use MyRelativeLayout; the same way you use RelativeLayout.

But just for overwriting Padding, I will not suggest you to create your own widget. My above, solution should be better approach for it.

Comment: It appears that your solution is for changing the RelativeLayout programatically.  I want some elements to have their own layout, different from RelativeLayout.

Comment: You can create your own widget and use them in your Layout file.


package com.android.xxx

public class MyRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {

}



in Your Layout file, use MyRelativeLayout; the same way you use RelativeLayout.

<com.android.xxx.MyRelativeLayout  />

But just for overwriting Padding, I will not suggest you to create your own widget. My above, solution should be better approach for it.